# Why activity indicator in didSelectRowAtIndex appears so late?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a UITableView and want when I tap on cell will appears activity indicator on screen, but it appears just a half of a second, before the segue performs.

My two functions:

```
func showActivityIndicator() {
    self.loadingView.alpha = 1
    self.loading.alpha = 1
}

func hideActivityIndicator() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.loadingView.alpha = 0
        self.loading.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

and in the

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    showActivityIndicator()
    selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
    performSegueWithIdentifier("body", sender: nil)
    hideActivityIndicator()
}
```

but I select a row, then wait-wait-wait and in the end, when segue starts perform it appears for half of a second and - the next screen. User does not see how it loading. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: why is your hide in an async block?

Comment: @Fonix I just tried it. The problem is in show func

Comment: are you using any other async blocks when changing UI elements states? because that does mess with the UI (causes strange delays), all need to be synchronous on main thread/queue

Comment: @Fonix no, just in this case I used it